# Anonymous Methods: Variable Binding vs. var Parameters

Tags: delphi, anonymous-methods

I wonder - given the case that the reference to the anonymous method lives no longer than the bound variables, for example when using it as a callback - if there's a difference in space requirements or performance or whatever between

1. Binding a Variable in an Anonymous Method by simply using it inside
2. Passing a Variable into an Anonymous Method by var Parameter

Example for case 1:

```
type 
  TCallback = reference to procedure (LogMsg: string);

procedure Log(Msg: string; Callback: TCallback)
begin
  Callback(Msg + '(' + DateTimeToStr(Now) + ')');
end;

procedure Test;
var
  Suffix: string;
  Callback: TCallback;
begin
  Suffix := '12345';
  Callback := 
    procedure (LogMsg: string)
    begin
      ShowMessage(LogMsg + Suffix);
      Delete(Suffix, 1, 1);
    end);
  Log('Test1', Callback);
  Log('Test2', Callback);
  Log('Test3', Callback);
end;
```

Example for case 2:

```
type 
  TCallback = reference to procedure (LogMsg: string; var Suf: string);

procedure Log(Msg: string; Callback: TCallback; var Suf: string)
begin
  Callback(Msg + '(' + DateTimeToStr(Now) + ')', Suf);
end;

procedure Test;
var
  Suffix: string;
  Callback: TCallback;
begin
  Suffix := '12345';
  Callback := 
    procedure (LogMsg: string; var Suf: string)
    begin
      ShowMessage(LogMsg + Suf);
      Delete(Suf, 1, 1);
    end);
  Log('Test1', Callback, Suffix);
  Log('Test2', Callback, Suffix);
  Log('Test3', Callback, Suffix);
end;
```

If I didn't make a mistake, these two should both give the following values:

```
Test112345
Test22345
Test3345
```

The Question is: Is any of these two potentially more performant (especially if used with bigger Values than a single string), more memory efficient, more whatever, or are they absolutely equal?

I know there is a difference in variable lifetime, if the reference to the Anonymous Method would live longer than the bound variables, but this discussion shall be solely about the case when the reference doesn't live longer than the bound variables.

Comment: The correct term is: variable capturing. That means that the lifetime of the variable is extended. There are cases where you want exactly that. It's like the question if you want to pass a value to the constructor of an object or as argument to a method call.

Comment: As a general rule, parameters are more efficient than captured variables. Whether or not that matters depends on the context.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that's what I thought and exactly what I wanted to address here. Could you please explain in detail or link some documents? I wasn't able to find the right keywords in google to find any, it's nearly all just about how to use these Anonymous Methods and what can be done with it, but never about the performance issues.

Comment: I don't know any such docs. Just do the profiling.